# Need a faster and efficient way to add elements to a list in python

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, python-3.x, parsing

I am trying create a large list of numbers .
`a = '1 1 1 2 2 0 0 1 1 1 1 9 9 0 0'` (it goes over a ten million).

I've  tried these methods:

1. `%timeit l = list(map(int, a.split()))` it was  `4.07 µs per loop`
2. `%timeit l = a.split(' ')` this was `462 ns per loop`
3. `%timeit l = [i for i in a.split()]` it took `1.19 µs per loop`

I understand that the 2nd and 3rd variants are character lists whereas first is an integer list, this is fine. But as the number of elements gets to over ten million, it can take up to 6 seconds to create a list. This is too long for my purposes.
Could someone tell me a more faster and efficient way to do this.

Thanks

Comment: The input is a string of space separated characters , i need it to be a list, so that it is mutable.

Comment: Just curious, what is an acceptable speed for this?  Processing 10million items on the order of seconds seems sensible

Comment: This a part of a bigger code, so i was trying to see if i could cut down on time here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In plain Python, not using a third-party extension, `a.split()` ought to be the fastest way to split your input into a list.  The `str.split()` function only has one job and it is specialized for this use.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. I was wondering if there was a faster way.

Comment: Tried with other sets of data and str.split() was the fastest method i found.

Answer (score 3):

If you know your input consists of single digits separated by single spaces then you can also consider:

```
b = ord('0')
[ord(a)-b for a in A[::2]]
```

this makes a list of 10 million integers in 0.2 seconds on my computer.

Answer (score 2):

I tested the various answers in a `jupyter` notebook, and Peter de Rivas does seem to edge out the others proposed.

[image]

Interestingly, **the mapping to integer seems to be the bottleneck**.  The `str.split()` operation itself is an order of magnitude faster.

[image]

Comment: If you want to test with my method, it only works if single digit numbers are used, so change str(x) to str(x%10) when you make digit_string (this should make it about 3 times faster)

Comment: Ahh yup sorry, updating answer!  Why is using `Ord` faster than casting to Int?

Comment: So it does seem that `str.split()` function  ,as @Raymond Hettinger mentioned, is the most optimised way to store a elements to a list.

Comment: @ranger_sim_g Yes, the mapping to int is the slow part.